# How to refresh token using AWS coginto auth sdk

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, access-token

I am working on a feature of refreshing token once it's expire. I used amazon-cognito-auth-js to do the authorization and check [here](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-auth-js/issues/154) as an example, I implemented the below method to refresh token. however it doesn't work.
Below is my code, and the session doesn't refresh as I expected. There is no synax error, just the auth token still expired.
By the way, I use react.

```
import { CognitoAuth } from 'amazon-cognito-auth-js';
class Main extends Component {
   constructor() {
        this.state = {
            auth: ""
       }
   }
   componentDidMount() {
        //some logic to get the auth once user login success
        //here is the logic  to update the correct auth into the state
        this.setState({
            auth: auth
        })
    }
 //here is the method that check the token expire or not, if expire, refresh the token and update the state
   checkTokenExpiration (){
        let auth = this.state.auth;
        let user = auth.getCachedSession();
 //ideally, there shall have the logic to check the session is expired or not
// anyidea how to write it?
        auth.refreshSession(user.getRefreshToken().getToken());
        this.setState({
            auth:auth
        })
}

}
```

Comment: You don't need to do anything! If you're using cognito SDK to authenticate, the SDK will refresh the token for you, no code required. If you're having a specific issue around token expiry you might need to open a different question.

Comment: @F_SO_K I figure out the solution. Once the session expire, just login again, and it will give me the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I close this question by myself.
My solution is set up a timer in the frontend, once timer is over 1hr(for example). Just let user logout.
[Here](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-auth-js/issues/92) is why you shall not refreshing token in the SPA.
And [here](https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-auth-js/issues/118) is the solution for dealing with refresh_token expire